# ActiveMQ data and conf folder needs to be changed to different file system in Linux

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I have downloaded and setup ActiveMQ 5.15.0 in my machine and followed this [guide.](https://activemq.apache.org/getting-started)

In `conf` folder I see in `conf/log4j.properties` there is a line with the path for Log Location.

```
log4j.appender.logfile.file=${activemq.data}/activemq.log
```

How this variable `${activemq.data}` is configured and how to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value for `${activemq.data}` is read from the environment variable `$ACTIVEMQ_DATA` by the `activemq` script when starting the broker. For example, when you start the broker using the default configuration you'll see this logged:

```
$ ./activemq console
...
ACTIVEMQ_HOME: /home/jbertram/java/apache-activemq-5.15.8
ACTIVEMQ_BASE: /home/jbertram/java/apache-activemq-5.15.8
ACTIVEMQ_CONF: /home/jbertram/java/apache-activemq-5.15.8/conf
ACTIVEMQ_DATA: /home/jbertram/java/apache-activemq-5.15.8/data
Loading message broker from: xbean:activemq.xml
...
```

However, if you set the `$ACTIVEMQ_DATA` variable to something else, e.g.:

```
$ export ACTIVEMQ_DATA=/tmp
```

Then this will be logged:

```
$ ./activemq console
...
ACTIVEMQ_HOME: /home/jbertram/java/apache-activemq-5.15.8
ACTIVEMQ_BASE: /home/jbertram/java/apache-activemq-5.15.8
ACTIVEMQ_CONF: /home/jbertram/java/apache-activemq-5.15.8/conf
ACTIVEMQ_DATA: /tmp
Loading message broker from: xbean:activemq.xml
...
```

You can also change this using the `bin/env` file. This is what the default `env` contains:

```
...
# Active MQ installation dirs
# ACTIVEMQ_HOME="<Installationdir>/"
# ACTIVEMQ_BASE="$ACTIVEMQ_HOME"
# ACTIVEMQ_CONF="$ACTIVEMQ_BASE/conf"
# ACTIVEMQ_DATA="$ACTIVEMQ_BASE/data"
# ACTIVEMQ_TMP="$ACTIVEMQ_BASE/tmp"
...
```

You could change this to be something like this:

```
...
# Active MQ installation dirs
# ACTIVEMQ_HOME="<Installationdir>/"
# ACTIVEMQ_BASE="$ACTIVEMQ_HOME"
# ACTIVEMQ_CONF="$ACTIVEMQ_BASE/conf"
ACTIVEMQ_DATA="/tmp"
# ACTIVEMQ_TMP="$ACTIVEMQ_BASE/tmp"
...
```

It's worth noting that ActiveMQ "Classic" 5.15.0 was released in June of 2017 (i.e. over 5 years ago now). I strongly recommend you upgrade to a more recent release, ideally [the latest](https://activemq.apache.org/components/classic/download/).